# Is \$f_{\text{hfe}}\$ independent of BJT capacitances?

Tags: analog, bjt, frequency-response

Bipolar junction transistors (BJTs) exhibit a gain rolloff as a function of frequency known as \$f_{\text{hfe}}\$, closely related to the device's *transition frequency*, \$f_T\$. As I understand it, this phenomenon is related to the *transit time* of carriers through some parts of the device.

Is this phenomena distinct from the frequency response characteristics of a BJT caused by its various capacitances such as \$C_\text{BC}\$? Or is it just a convenient way of thinking about the frequency dependent behaviors of those capacitances under typical operating conditions?

The reason I'm asking is I want to understand the role of \$f_{\text{hfe}}\$ in characterizing the frequency response of a BJT amplifier. I'm taking from some of the sources I've been studying that \$f_{\text{hfe}}\$ can be considered separately from any poles produced by the interaction of, for example, \$R_{\text{input}}\$ with \$C_{\text{bc}}\$, but other sources seem to neglect \$f_{\text{hfe}}\$ altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you probably know, \$\beta\$ or \$H_{\text{fe}}\$ is in first order determined by the ratio of the doping of base and emitter. This doping ratio is intrinsic (determined during manufacturing), it has no frequency dependency. What does limit the frequency behaviour though is the carrier mobility. This explains why there are Silicon-Germanium (SiGe) based Bipolar Junction Transistors which have a higher \$f_{\text{hfe}}\$. The SiGe has higher mobility resulting in faster transistors. SiGe is not the only option, for more look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterojunction_bipolar_transistor).

You are correct in that all (parasitic) capacitances also limit the high frequency gain of BJTs. However, in high frequency designs it is common practice to make these capacitors part of LC resonator tanks allowing them to be tuned out. Meaning they form a resonant tank with an inductor and thus eliminating their frequency limiting effect.

I think it depends on how far away a design is from the \$f_{\text{hfe}}\$ limit to decide if you can ignore \$f_{\text{hfe}}\$ or that you have to take it into account. If the \$R_{\text{input}}\$ and \$C_{\text{bc}}\$ are limiting, then you can neglect \$f_{\text{hfe}}\$. That's what experienced designers do to make their life easier ;-)

Comment: It was my pleasure.